# Windows 10 IoT does not automatically use the Real Time Clock module to automatically update the system time

Tags: windows-iot, rtc, system-clock

bought a brand new Raspberry Pi 3 DS3231 RTC Module and integrated to correct gpio pins as it should be. But somehow Windows 10 IOT seems not detect this module. than attempted to follow follow instructions. but what! all instructions are for linux. and as I know there is no sudo command etc in powershell for windows 10 to make IOT to detect this module.

dtoverlay=i2c-rtc,ds3231
line above added into config.txt. no luck.

so how can I make Windows 10 IOT detect the rtc module ?

[instructions are here for linux.](https://thepihut.com/blogs/raspberry-pi-tutorials/17209332-adding-a-real-time-clock-to-your-raspberry-pi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by Windows 10 IoT does not detect the module though what I suspect you mean is that Windows 10 IoT does not automatically use the Real Time Clock module to automatically update the system time.

Windows 10 IoT does do a network time check to synchronize the system time with a network time source similar to what Linux does. However if your Raspberry Pi is off line and doesn't have access to a time source then that doesn't do you much good.

The problem with Windows 10 IoT development and UWP applications is that much of the Win32 API is not available with Windows 10 IoT in the sandbox environment. It appears that the only way of setting the Windows 10 IoT system time is using Powershell.

You can retrieve time from the Real Time Clock when your application starts up using I2C to talk to the Real Time Clock device.

Here are a couple of resources for you.

On StackOverflow there is a question about setting the Windows 10 IoT system clock, [How to set system time in Windows 10 IoT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30585900/how-to-set-system-time-in-windows-10-iot) and see as well [How do I set the time in Winodws ioT ?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/016b0842-2fda-4780-8f97-c701fb0dc3be/how-do-i-set-the-time-in-winodws-iot-?forum=WindowsIoT) with an answer describing a procedure using Powershell.

On StackOverflow there is a question with an answer using C# code for what looks to be a UWP application [Windows IoT and DS3231 RTC clock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34964682/windows-iot-and-ds3231-rtc-clock)

On CodeProject there is an article, again C# within a UWP application, [Adding the Missing Real Time Clock to Windows IoT on Raspberry Pi](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1113626/Adding-the-Missing-Real-Time-Clock-to-Windows-IoT) with a complete project

Finally there is the possibility of using a Raspberry Pi as a network time clock.

See [The Raspberry Pi as a Stratum-1 NTP Server](http://www.satsignal.eu/ntp/Raspberry-Pi-NTP.html)